# How to select a document and its child elements inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LfkbSMUAAAAAHPAhDmPr5ZmSg0ijddy8kqz4WRP&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmF5bWFjay5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=53001mhu4to3" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
```

Google's recaptcha is just an iframe but at runtime it expands to a document nested under it like this

```
#document
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <style type="text/css">
         /* cyrillic-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
         }
         /* cyrillic */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
         }
         /* greek-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
         }
         /* greek */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
         }
         /* vietnamese */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
         }
         /* latin-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
         }
         /* latin */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 400;
         src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
         }
         /* cyrillic-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
         }
         /* cyrillic */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
         }
         /* greek-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
         }
         /* greek */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
         }
         /* vietnamese */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
         }
         /* latin-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
         }
         /* latin */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
         }
         /* cyrillic-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
         }
         /* cyrillic */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
         }
         /* greek-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
         }
         /* greek */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
         }
         /* vietnamese */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
         }
         /* latin-ext */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
         }
         /* latin */
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 900;
         src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
         unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
         }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1526338122299/styles__ltr.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1526338122299/recaptcha__en.js" nonce=""></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//www.google.com/js/bg/hAmfqrFPh_wgMqcsWne70WcGW0vN3zpqZb32EEucCfk.js" nonce=""></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="rc-anchor-alert"></div>
      <input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token" value="03AJpayVFgyts_fMGQS1DJFJfu8ycaf4xnEfPFq-9tgEZL27bAzfNbAuVlO9wRpTkY0zEBRn4QKWenKxObtkVm0PVRd5WebmH-jsAWCClwnKa4BTLwHyD0jkPlTcm5axm0E0C3O6NiP3owO7eoTCz-ol78sPh6BSHZL5v6ngf4J2tMX41ZAN2AeSNshE4kAZf5vkC2hOeIzXU7oxRFgbll3Q1a60JDuhnVlZspxe8_L5AFXKIx14vNBY__pDxkH-yOGrVG1oSRRwyZYy-TsU0pSnzpi1amqqrwIEzAkb6FW7yG5i1sZYN8KFhCQbzjin6rAnPk9tlPj4LpeBT76rAdzNswFtEreC6I7WCdlyNSLrsFtOfks5xCGIEPmRdvGJwe0r8YiWlhlTE89JbxOnmRquKi94wZA0xfqg">
      <script nonce="">'use strict';try{(function(){window.gd_||(window.gd_={});window.gd_.gd_=function(){var a=function(a,b){a=document.createElement(a);a.id=b;return a},e=a("div","id_1"),h=a("div","id_1"),R=a("u","id_2");h.appendChild(R);var S=a("frame","id_3");h.appendChild(S);var T=a("thead","id_4");h.appendChild(T);var U=a("label","id_5");h.appendChild(U);var n=a("h3","id_6"),V=a("dd","id_7");n.appendChild(V);var W=a("tt","id_8");n.appendChild(W);var X=a("b","id_9");n.appendChild(X);var z=a("h2","id_10"),Y=a("noframes",
         "id_11");z.appendChild(Y);var A=a("center","id_12"),Z=a("object","id_13");A.appendChild(Z);var H=a("address","id_14"),p=a("ol","id_15"),aa=a("frame","id_16");p.appendChild(aa);var ba=a("acronym","id_17");p.appendChild(ba);var ca=a("meta","id_18");p.appendChild(ca);var da=a("tfoot","id_19");p.appendChild(da);var ea=a("p","id_20");p.appendChild(ea);H.appendChild(p);var fa=a("param","id_21");H.appendChild(fa);A.appendChild(H);var ha=a("samp","id_22");A.appendChild(ha);z.appendChild(A);var ia=a("tt",
         "id_23");z.appendChild(ia);n.appendChild(z);var ja=a("style","id_24");n.appendChild(ja);h.appendChild(n);var ka=a("table","id_25");h.appendChild(ka);e.appendChild(h);var c=a("div","id_1"),la=a("area","id_2");c.appendChild(la);var ma=a("thead","id_3");c.appendChild(ma);var na=a("style","id_4");c.appendChild(na);var M=a("form","id_5"),oa=a("strong","id_6");M.appendChild(oa);c.appendChild(M);var pa=a("thead","id_7");c.appendChild(pa);var qa=a("basefont","id_8");c.appendChild(qa);var v=a("ol","id_9"),
         ra=a("del","id_10");v.appendChild(ra);var sa=a("script","id_11");v.appendChild(sa);var ta=a("tbody","id_12");v.appendChild(ta);var ua=a("col","id_13");v.appendChild(ua);c.appendChild(v);var va=a("span","id_14");c.appendChild(va);var wa=a("thead","id_15");c.appendChild(wa);var xa=a("col","id_16");c.appendChild(xa);var ya=a("bdo","id_17");c.appendChild(ya);var k=a("center","id_18"),za=a("tr","id_19");k.appendChild(za);var Aa=a("script","id_20");k.appendChild(Aa);var Ba=a("param","id_21");k.appendChild(Ba);
         var Ca=a("meta","id_22");k.appendChild(Ca);var Da=a("center","id_23");k.appendChild(Da);var Ea=a("iframe","id_24");k.appendChild(Ea);c.appendChild(k);var Fa=a("font","id_25");c.appendChild(Fa);e.appendChild(c);var f=a("div","id_1"),Ga=a("isindex","id_2");f.appendChild(Ga);var Ha=a("big","id_3");f.appendChild(Ha);var Ia=a("dir","id_4");f.appendChild(Ia);var Ja=a("font","id_5");f.appendChild(Ja);var Ka=a("img","id_6");f.appendChild(Ka);var B=a("h4","id_7"),N=a("h2","id_8"),La=a("s","id_9");N.appendChild(La);
         B.appendChild(N);var w=a("dir","id_10"),Ma=a("script","id_11");w.appendChild(Ma);var Na=a("area","id_12");w.appendChild(Na);var q=a("h3","id_13"),O=a("h3","id_14"),Oa=a("strike","id_15");O.appendChild(Oa);q.appendChild(O);var Pa=a("select","id_16");q.appendChild(Pa);var Qa=a("fieldset","id_17");q.appendChild(Qa);var C=a("center","id_18"),Ra=a("noframes","id_19");C.appendChild(Ra);var Sa=a("big","id_20");C.appendChild(Sa);var Ta=a("dl","id_21");C.appendChild(Ta);q.appendChild(C);var Ua=a("input","id_22");
         q.appendChild(Ua);w.appendChild(q);var Va=a("a","id_23");w.appendChild(Va);B.appendChild(w);var Wa=a("frame","id_24");B.appendChild(Wa);f.appendChild(B);var Xa=a("area","id_25");f.appendChild(Xa);e.appendChild(f);var b=a("div","id_1"),Ya=a("textarea","id_2");b.appendChild(Ya);var Za=a("dfn","id_3");b.appendChild(Za);var D=a("form","id_4"),$a=a("code","id_5");D.appendChild($a);var ab=a("q","id_6");D.appendChild(ab);var bb=a("li","id_7");D.appendChild(bb);b.appendChild(D);var cb=a("tfoot","id_8");b.appendChild(cb);
         var db=a("cite","id_9");b.appendChild(db);var eb=a("dir","id_10");b.appendChild(eb);var fb=a("cite","id_11");b.appendChild(fb);var gb=a("noframes","id_12");b.appendChild(gb);var hb=a("sub","id_13");b.appendChild(hb);var ib=a("big","id_14");b.appendChild(ib);var jb=a("u","id_15");b.appendChild(jb);var I=a("div","id_16"),kb=a("kbd","id_17");I.appendChild(kb);var lb=a("i","id_18");I.appendChild(lb);b.appendChild(I);var mb=a("title","id_19");b.appendChild(mb);var nb=a("tbody","id_20");b.appendChild(nb);
         var ob=a("strong","id_21");b.appendChild(ob);var pb=a("title","id_22");b.appendChild(pb);var qb=a("dt","id_23");b.appendChild(qb);var rb=a("col","id_24");b.appendChild(rb);var sb=a("samp","id_25");b.appendChild(sb);e.appendChild(b);var d=a("div","id_1"),tb=a("font","id_2");d.appendChild(tb);var ub=a("param","id_3");d.appendChild(ub);var vb=a("strong","id_4");d.appendChild(vb);var wb=a("ins","id_5");d.appendChild(wb);var xb=a("a","id_6");d.appendChild(xb);var yb=a("u","id_7");d.appendChild(yb);var zb=
         a("strong","id_8");d.appendChild(zb);var Ab=a("button","id_9");d.appendChild(Ab);var Bb=a("colgroup","id_10");d.appendChild(Bb);var Cb=a("frameset","id_11");d.appendChild(Cb);var Db=a("body","id_12");d.appendChild(Db);var l=a("hr","id_13"),Eb=a("strong","id_14");l.appendChild(Eb);var Fb=a("link","id_15");l.appendChild(Fb);var Gb=a("code","id_16");l.appendChild(Gb);var Hb=a("select","id_17");l.appendChild(Hb);var r=a("dir","id_18"),Ib=a("select","id_19");r.appendChild(Ib);var Jb=a("strong","id_20");
         r.appendChild(Jb);var Kb=a("tbody","id_21");r.appendChild(Kb);var Lb=a("table","id_22");r.appendChild(Lb);var Mb=a("fieldset","id_23");r.appendChild(Mb);l.appendChild(r);var Nb=a("dt","id_24");l.appendChild(Nb);d.appendChild(l);var Ob=a("link","id_25");d.appendChild(Ob);e.appendChild(d);var x=a("div","id_1"),Pb=a("colgroup","id_2");x.appendChild(Pb);var Qb=a("colgroup","id_3");x.appendChild(Qb);var g=a("h3","id_4"),Rb=a("area","id_5");g.appendChild(Rb);var Sb=a("option","id_6");g.appendChild(Sb);
         var Tb=a("style","id_7");g.appendChild(Tb);var E=a("noscript","id_8"),Ub=a("thead","id_9");E.appendChild(Ub);var Vb=a("tt","id_10");E.appendChild(Vb);var Wb=a("samp","id_11");E.appendChild(Wb);g.appendChild(E);var Xb=a("table","id_12");g.appendChild(Xb);var t=a("h1","id_13"),Yb=a("title","id_14");t.appendChild(Yb);var Zb=a("kbd","id_15");t.appendChild(Zb);var $b=a("label","id_16");t.appendChild($b);var y=a("ul","id_17"),ac=a("small","id_18");y.appendChild(ac);var bc=a("caption","id_19");y.appendChild(bc);
         var P=a("h1","id_20"),cc=a("h1","id_21");P.appendChild(cc);y.appendChild(P);var dc=a("em","id_22");y.appendChild(dc);t.appendChild(y);var ec=a("col","id_23");t.appendChild(ec);g.appendChild(t);var fc=a("code","id_24");g.appendChild(fc);x.appendChild(g);var gc=a("head","id_25");x.appendChild(gc);e.appendChild(x);var F=a("div","id_1"),Q=a("dl","id_2"),G=a("hr","id_3"),hc=a("noframes","id_4");G.appendChild(hc);var J=a("h3","id_5"),u=a("h1","id_6"),ic=a("script","id_7");u.appendChild(ic);var jc=a("tt",
         "id_8");u.appendChild(jc);var kc=a("dd","id_9");u.appendChild(kc);var m=a("address","id_10"),lc=a("b","id_11");m.appendChild(lc);var K=a("h2","id_12"),mc=a("abbr","id_13");K.appendChild(mc);var L=a("h1","id_14"),nc=a("frame","id_15");L.appendChild(nc);var oc=a("strong","id_16");L.appendChild(oc);K.appendChild(L);m.appendChild(K);var pc=a("strong","id_17");m.appendChild(pc);var qc=a("a","id_18");m.appendChild(qc);var rc=a("noscript","id_19");m.appendChild(rc);var sc=a("meta","id_20");m.appendChild(sc);
         u.appendChild(m);var tc=a("h2","id_21");u.appendChild(tc);J.appendChild(u);var uc=a("thead","id_22");J.appendChild(uc);G.appendChild(J);var vc=a("dt","id_23");G.appendChild(vc);Q.appendChild(G);F.appendChild(Q);var wc=a("cite","id_24");F.appendChild(wc);var xc=a("textarea","id_25");F.appendChild(xc);e.appendChild(F);return e}})()}catch(a){};
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" nonce="">
         recaptcha.anchor.Main.init("");
      </script>
      <div class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
         <div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">Verification challenge expired, check the checkbox again for a new challenge</div>
         <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
         <div class="rc-anchor-content">
            <div class="rc-inline-block">
               <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
                  <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder">
                     <span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation" style=""></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rc-inline-block">
               <div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label"><span aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>I'm not a robot</label></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer">
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
               <div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div>
               <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't access a cross domain iframe due to *same origin policy*

Comment: once I right click the iframe and inspect I am able to access the selectors inside in a browser console. is there a way to do equivalent of this second inspect programatically ?

Comment: No. There is not unless you control the source code in both page and iframe

Comment: how does controlling source help can you elaborate ?

Comment: you can use things like postMessage to communicate between the windows https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: My point is how difficult it is when you can do the same thing with mouse. why not via javascript. I am trying ti scroll to position then click when it reaches on top of captcha

Comment: Because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171564/discussion-between-ishandutta2007-and-charlietfl).